# SQL server agent issues: Imports wizard + manual SSIS execution ok . SQL server agent fails --> Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 not registered. 32/64bit

Tags: oledbconnection, sql-server-agent

Trying to schedule an SSIS package to do a daily update from an excel file to a SQL server.

Imports fine in imports wizard, created the SSIS package, SSIS package manually executes fine, but when it comes to SQL server agent, it fails.  Tried both runtime 32bit and default settings.

---

This is the history log:

Message
Executed as user: TRANSFORMATION\svc_biagent. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 13.0.4224.16 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft. All rights reserved.    Started:  9:44:36 PM  Error: 2022-07-21 21:44:36.97     Code: 0xC0209303     Source: mockdata Connection manager "SourceConnectionExcel"     Description: The requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is not registered. If the 64-bit driver is not installed, run the package in 32-bit mode. Error code: 0x00000000.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Service Components"  Hresult: 0x80040154  Description: "Class not registered".  End Error  Error: 2022-07-21 21:44:36.97     Code: 0xC001002B     Source: mockdata Connection manager "SourceConnectionExcel"     Description: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=219816  End Error  Error: 2022-07-21 21:44:36.97     Code: 0xC020801C     Source: Data Flow Task 1 Source - MockData$ [23]     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "SourceConnectionExcel" failed with error code 0xC0209303.

---

Whats installed:

SSMS/SSIS 2016  (imports wizard is 32bit)

Office 2019

AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe

AccessDatabaseEngine.exe

Both 64bit and 32bit ODBC drivers are installed.

There are lots of mentions about this issue on here, and all solutions point to reinstalling the AccessDatabaseEngine numerous times, which I have tried again no avail.  It imports fine in the imports wizard and SSIS, but not SQL server agent.

Doing a SQL server check of oledb sources this is what I get:

[SQL OLEDB source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAzbg.png)

So not really sure what is happening, can anyone help?

Comment: I would suggest that you didn't change the package to run in 32bit mode. What did you do to change the package to run in 32bit?

Comment: Just to check, when using the wizard and manually running, is it on the same environment/machine than where it is running when executed through the SQL server agent?

Comment: Hi Larnu - As I have said above, I have switched it to 32bit runtime and it has not made a difference.

Comment: Hi Inus, it is on the same machine.   Data Imports wizard is started from SSMS 2016, and SQL server agent job is scheduled from there also.